# Conditions on LU factorisation of tridiagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, positive-definite

My course notes on iterative methods make the following claim

> If $T$ is a symmetric, positive definite and tridiagonal $k \times k$ matrix, it has a $LU$ factorisation without pivoting. We can write $T = LU$ with
>   $$
> L = \begin{bmatrix}
> \delta_0 \\
> \phi_0 & \delta_1 \\
> & \phi_1 & \ddots \\
> & & \ddots & \ddots \\
> & & & \phi_{k - 2} & \delta_{k-1} \\
> \end{bmatrix} \quad
> U = \begin{bmatrix}
> 1 & \epsilon_{0} \\
> & 1 & \epsilon_1 \\
> & & \ddots & \ddots \\
> & & & \ddots & \epsilon_{k-2} \\
> & & & & 1 \\
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>   for certain real numbers $\delta_i$, $\phi_i$, $\epsilon_i$.

No proof or reference is given whatsoever. I found [these notes](http://www.webpages.uidaho.edu/~barannyk/Teaching/LU_factorization_tridiagonal.pdf) which give an algorithm to determine the numbers $\delta_i$, $\phi_i$ and $\epsilon_i$ assuming that they exist, but clearly this is not the case for any symmetric, tridiagonal matrix. How does the positive definiteness ensure that such a factorisation exists? It's just a theoretical result that's needed, I don't really need an algorithm.

Comment: Symmetric positive definite implies that you don't need pivoting.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that? I never heard of that fact. And even if I accept that positive definite doesn't require pivoting, why do the matrices in the composition necessarily have this bidiagonal structure?

Comment: that because $T$ is already tridiagonal. The band width remains the same (in absent of pivoting). Just check the formulas of LU decomposition. As for symmetric and positive definite, that is proven by induction. The diagonal is always positive. The new $n-1\times n-1$ sub matrix after a LU step is again symmetric and positive definite. Just google. Both facts are well known.

Comment: Apparently they are, since my course notes didn't bother to reference anything. I'll take another look at it after a night of sleep.

Comment: A [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#Existence_and_uniqueness) characterization of the existence of the LU factorization is related to the nonsingularity of leading principal submatrices. The statement follows since any principal submatrix of an SPD matrix is SPD and any SPD matrix is nonsingular.